# Xamarin forms ios sdk versions mismatch issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I recently updated my Visual studio for windows and mac. I also updated the Xcode to 10.2. The visual studio 2017 for windows version is 15.9.11 and the xamarin ios sdk version is 12.4.0.64. My visual studio version of mac 2019 community is 8.0.2 and xamarin ios version is 12.8.0. Why I did these updates is I got a mono version mismatch issue when compiling ios app. After these updates the mono version conflict resolved but now it shows xamarin ios version mismatch error. How can I solve this? I am trying to solve these for some days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not install Visual Studio 2019 also on Windows? That might already help getting the versions aligned

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Is there any other way to solve this bro?

Comment: Maybe if you find a manual download to the right version, but you probably can't find that

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes bro I tried. I cant find it

Comment: Then I guess updating to VS2019 for Windows is your only option

Comment: Can you please Check Xcode —> Preference —> Locations —> check which Xcode is selected and in visual studio which Xcode is Select make sure both visual studio pointing same Xcode  after that remove obj bin and Rebuild the Project